# WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,recall

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, validation, keras

I have the error in the title when running the code below:

```
def create_model(learning_rate, dropout, l2_lambda):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128,input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2_lambda)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(64,  activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2_lambda)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['Recall'])
    return model


early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)


for i in range (2):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y)

    
    steps = [('transformer', PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson')),
     ('scaler', RobustScaler()), 
     ('smote', SMOTE()),
     ('model', KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=2, callbacks=[early_stopping]))]


    # Create the pipeline object
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

    # Define the k-fold cross-validation
    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)


    # Create the grid search object
    grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=cv, return_train_score=True, error_score='raise', scoring='recall')

    # Fit the grid search to the data
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train, model__validation_split=0.2)

    grbe=grid.best_estimator_.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Any ideas on how to solve it? I have search for similar error but I cannot apply the solutions in my case

Comment: Can you show the create_model function as well?

Comment: What I noticed is that in the last `fit` call (`grbe=...`) you did not specify validation data. This means that the `val_loss` metric does not exist, because there are no validation data to run it on. Did that help?

Comment: @Znerual yes this help. But does it correct to specify validation data on the second fit?

The second fit is used to fit the .best_estimator to the data

However the best estimator has been defined based on the first fit using the  validation data

Comment: I don't think you have used the validation data you created (with the split). because you always used cv to validate the model. So yes, it is definitively valid to use the validation data there.

Comment: @Znerual write an answer so as to accept your answer. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the validation data to the final fit call

```
grbe=grid.best_estimator_.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

otherwise, the metric `val_loss` can not be calculated, because there is no validation data.